# remove rows with certain dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Using python 3.7, pandas 1.1.1

I have dataframe with datetimeindex and list of date_list =["2020-07-19", "2020-07-24", ... etc]

I want to remove all rows in my dataframe that contain dates in date_list.

My datetimeindex contains variety of hh:mm:ss as well and no matter its time I want to remove if its dates are in date_list

dataframe looks like this:

```
      time              data
2020-07-19 23:52:02       1
2020-07-20 13:44:02       1
2020-07-22 23:52:02       1
2020-07-24 08:52:02       1
2020-07-24 21:52:02       1
```

desired output would be:

```
      time              data
2020-07-20 13:44:02       1
2020-07-22 23:52:02       1
```

deleting dates in date_list

following [How can I delete rows for a particular Date in a Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372499/how-can-i-delete-rows-for-a-particular-date-in-a-pandas-dataframe)
I've tried `df.drop(pd.to_datetime("2020-07-19"))` which give `KeyError: "[Timestamp('2020-07-19 00:00:00')] not found in axis"`

How can I remove dates without considering its time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `time` are not exact `00:00:00` on the day, you can use `normalize()` to extract the date. Then you can use `isin`:

```
date_list = pd.to_datetime(date_list)

df[~df['time'].dt.normalize().isin(date_list)]
```

If `time` is the index:

```
df[~df.index.normalize().isin(date_list)]
```

Comment: Thanks this works but I need to df.reset_index() and then use it, can I do it with index?

Comment: Is `time` column the index of your `df`?

Comment: Amazing! could you explain why we need extra .dt when `time` is set as column and without .dt when `time` is set as index?

Comment: @Ambleu not sure why. Probably a good question to Pandas' dev. I personally find it confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Check

```
df[~df.index.to_series().dt.date.isin(date_list)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Though this outputs `TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable`

Comment: @QuangHoang ah that is right ~ I should test before posted, thank you man ~

Comment: This outputs `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isin'`

Answer (score 0):

Or using `str.contains`

```
df[~df["time"].str.contains('|'.join(date_list))]
```